# View with multiple layers dont relese memory

Tags: ios, swift, performance, memory, calayer

I create custom View:

```
final class Clock: UIView {

lazy var hourArrow: CALayer = {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hourArrow").cgImage
    layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
    return layer
}()

lazy var subLayers = [hourArrow,minuteArrow,centerDial,clockDial,clockArrow,block]


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    subLayers.forEach { (l) in
        layer.addSublayer(l)
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    subLayers.forEach({ l in
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        l.frame = rect
    })
}
```

}

and i use it ViewController:

```
class ClockViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var clock: Clock = {
    let clock = Clock(frame: .zero)
    clock.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return clock
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(clock)
    let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    clock.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    clock.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    clock.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    clock.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

}

then i move to this view controller, memory up to 10 MB with this layers.
When i dismiss VC, memory don't release but deinit was called.

(I must remove CALayer variables to post this, all of layers are create like first)

Any Ideas?

Comment: retain cycle probably. Are you using any blocks, timers, dispatches, etc?

Comment: PS: how you present your VC? If you adding it's view to view hierarchy manually, view will be retained by superviews. Please place breakpoint in deinit and check view.superview to make sure it's not the case.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov I dont use any block GDC.

Comment: i'm presenting VC using segue via storyboard

Comment: It's not too much information to make any deduction. I can advice you to debug deinit sequence, to determine what objects missing to deinit first. Override deninit in view to place breakpoint. If it fired - then problems seems in CALayers. So do the same for CALayer. When you find out what actually leaking - try to simplify all code related to it by commenting/uncommenting line by line until you find the cause. If you are working on something open source, you can share link to the project here.

Comment: i think the problem is in a timer that isn't being invalidated